# nodejs pdf2json missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, node.js

im new to Javascript nodejs, i tried to use modesty/pdf2json from hithub. But there is error showing missing ) syntax error, below are the codes and the sign of error in comment,

```
let fs = require('fs'),
    PDFParser = require("./pdf2json/PDFParser");

let pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData) );
    //Syntax error here missing ) at "errData"
pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
    let pJSON = JSON.stringify({"formImage": pdfData.data});
    //Syntax error here missing ) at "pdfData"

    fs.writeFile("./pdf2json/test/F1040EZ.json", pJSON, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error("parsing error: ", err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("parsing succeeded");
        }
    });
});

pdfParser.loadPDF("./pdf2json/test/pdf/fd/form/F1040EZ.pdf");

// or, call directly with buffer
fs.readFile(pdfFilePath, function (err, pdfBuffer) {
  if (!err) {
    pdfParser.parseBuffer(pdfBuffer);
  }
})
```

What is the meaning of "=>" ? Cause error tends to popup where line with this symbol.

Answer (score 1):

This is Arrow function which is introduced in ES6.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),

An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
         // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }

// A function with no parameters requires parentheses or an underscore:
() => { statements }
_ => { statements }
```

Can you give me information how you are executing this code?

**Update:**
Block scoped declaration is not allowed outside the strict mode yet. Therefore use strict mode in your script.

Comment: actually i execute this command using command
    node {filename}.js

Answer (score 0):

It is ES6 markup:

```
param => { }
```

is the same as:

```
function (param) { }
```

[Read more about ES6](http://es6-features.org/#StatementBodies)

---

code below works in node:

```
"use strict"
let fs = require("fs"),
    PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

let pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => { 
    console.error(errData) 
});

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
    let pJSON = JSON.stringify({
        "formImage": pdfData.data
    });

    fs.writeFile("./pdf2json/test/F1040EZ.json", pJSON, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("parsing error:", err);
        } else {
            console.log("parsing succeeded");
        }
    });
});

pdfParser.loadPDF("./pdf2json/test/pdf/fd/form/F1040EZ.pdf");
```

---

You can also try using the ES5 version of the code: (notice the functions and the `var` instead of `let`)

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

var pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", function (errData) { console.error(errData) });
pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", function (pdfData) {
    var pJSON = JSON.stringify({"formImage": pdfData.data});

    fs.writeFile("./pdf2json/test/F1040EZ.json", pJSON, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error("parsing error: ", err);
        } else {
            console.log("parsing succeeded");
        }
    });
});

pdfParser.loadPDF("./pdf2json/test/pdf/fd/form/F1040EZ.pdf");
```

Comment: This is nodeJS the OP is talking about. Why are you talking about browsers?

Comment: Still having error, isit because of my node version?
node   v3.3.1
nodejs  v0.10.25

Comment: That is indeed severely outdated. As far as I recall, node 0.10 had ES6 basic support, maybe you're encountering issues because of that. Let me make you an ES5 version.